# VS2010: Going to definition for a C# member in a VB.NET project (and vice versa)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, go-to-definition

I have a solution with a C# project and a VB.NET project.  The VB.NET project references the C# project.  When I am in the VB.NET project and want to go to definition of an object member located in the C# project, VS takes me to the object browser instead of the member.  The same occurs when I am doing the opposite in the C# project.  What I would like it to do is expose its member to me.

Note: I am referencing the actual project and not the DLL.

Comment: How are these projects referencing each other?

Comment: They hide it well, but sometimes it peeks through the cracks that the VB.NET and the C# IDE are completely different chunks of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known limitation of Visual Studio.  The corresponding Connect issue was closed as "By Design": http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/349633/go-to-definition-goes-to-object-browser-when-type-is-written-in-c-and-current-code-is-vb

Comment: Well that sahks.  Thanks for the link.  Now I know!